# Javascript create multiple strings from 2d array using MAP?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array maybe looks like this:

```
var array=[
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
]
```

How to get a result like this without using a simple for loop? (Using MAP constructor?!)

```
var result=[
    ['0000'],
    ['0000'],
    ['0000'],
    ['0000']
]
```

My for loops solution would be something like this, but is there a way to achieve the result without a for loop?

```js
var array=[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0]
]


var new_array=[]
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
  new_array.push(array[i].toString().replace(/,/g,''))

console.log(new_array)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have answered your question. Please take a look.

Comment: But your code is absolutely not the right solution for my question @JesseSchokker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the joined values.

```js
var array=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    result = array.map(a => [a.join('')]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not exactly the desired output. Should be `[ ["0000"], ["0000"], ... ]`. `a => [a.join('')]` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Nina. But thats not the exactly the solution I've searched for. I'd like to have get a 2d array like I've mentioned above. @Nina Scholz

Comment: @Jonas0000 Just wrap the `a.join('')` in brackets, as I mentioned in my edited comment above. That will give you the output you desire

Comment: Ahh. Sorry @mhodges. I've failed to see your comment :) Thanks